# Validate xml against two schemas using java

Tags: java, xml, validation

I want to validate an xml file that has a schemalocation given in the root element without having this file localy. I think I got this to work but the problem is this xml contains another schema that is located on another element in the xml file and I can't find a way do define to schemas to validate a single file. Can someone help me here?

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new URL(UrlToSchema));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
```

Also is the a way to get the variable UrlToSchema from the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an array of `StreamSource` to contain the list of xml schemas.
you can refer the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html) for this.

The code should look like this assuming that there are two xml schemas ie xsds

```
    StreamSource[] xsdSources = new StreamSource[2]; 
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("schema1.xsd"); 
    sources[0] = new StreamSource(fis1); 
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("schema2.xsd"); 
    sources[1] = new StreamSource(fis2); 
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdSources);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
```

In you case, to read from the ulr, you can use below code.

```
InputStream fis1 = new URL("http://www.somesite.com/schema1.xsd").openStream();
sources[0] = new StreamSource(fis1);
```

Comment: This  whould require me to download the schema files before validating the xml file. I whould like to use the URL defined in the schemaLocation in the xml file to validate the file.

Comment: You can also read using URL and you can store it StreamSource.

Comment: Thanks, now I just need a way to get the URLs from the xml file to parse in so I dont have to hardcode the URL for each type of xml file. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You can simply parse the xml file to get the url and other contents, but before parsing you need to validate. Since the XSDs are in other location, you need to provide. However you can maintain a constant file to maintain the xsd urls.